# Is it possible to write a non-HTTP servlet for Tomcat container?

Tags: java, tomcat, cloud-foundry

I would like to handle non-HTTP traffic, but (now it seems) I have to run it at Cloud Foundry ecosystem.

Is there any way to write (and push) a servlet which can handle raw TCP connections or is this against the whole servlet container design (as I can see now)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now TCP is not supported in Cloud Foundry.  However, TCP is coming this year.  Check out http://www.slideshare.net/Pivotal/cloud-foundry-summit-2014-cloud-foundry-roadmap for the roadmap!

Comment: All the answers are extremely true and useful. Actually I was looking for the answer spotlighted here. I hope CF will introduce TCP rproxy soon. Thank you for all!

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat listens to an HTTP port, and converts the requests sent to it on Java objects that passes to a servlet method.

You cannot make Tomcat listen to anything different than HTTP or HTTPS. So, if you have a class that handles raw TCP connections it will take no advantage of being in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets handle requests (not necessarily HTTP requests per the spec, but always requests). You could write code that would listen on a raw TCP socket, but that would have nothing to do with whether it's running in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

To add some more information about your original question of if it is possible to write a non-HTTP servlet for a Tomcat container, the answer is yes, this is very much possible. TomCat is preconfigured with built-in support for the HTTP protocol; however, it is not too farfetched of an idea that you can extend the servlet concept and adapt this to support other protocols on top of TCP/IP.

If you look at your servlet class, you will see that this class extends `HttpServlet`, and that `HttpServlet` extends the `GenericServlet` class. It would be up to you to create your own unique protocol class that extends `GenericServlet`. For example, you could create a `FTPServlet` or a `SMTPServlet` class. However, it will be up to you to investigate if the servlet paradigm is the best architecture to implement other protocols with. Wish you luck.